# How do I parse an HTML string and remove a div with a certain class?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a service return me an HTML snippet, in which there's a div with class "customerID", before I append this code to the DOM, I need to check if we have customerID in the model, then if not, I need to find the div in the snipped and remove it.

How is this achievable?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

- `dojo/dom-construct`
- `dojo/query`
- `dojo/NodeList-dom` (loading it enables the `orphan()` method)

In other words, probably something like:

```
var tempNode = domConstruct.toDom("<div>Hello world.</div>"); // Make a DOM fragment
var custDivList = query("div.customerID", node); // Find the problem divs and return nodeList
var removedNodes = custDivList.orphan(); // Remove each node in the list from its place
var scrubbedHtmlString = tempNode.innerHTML; // Get the final result
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers have indicated, it's probably best to parse the snippet you have and use dom manipulation methods to remove what you need to. This is similar to @Darien's answer but mine includes the required dependencies and is a working example.

```
require([
    'dojo/dom-construct',
    'dojo/query',
    'dojo/NodeList-dom', // provides query(...).orphan()
    'dojo/domReady!'
], function(dom_construct, query) {

    // get your html snippet; hardcoded here for convenience and example
    var html_snippet = [
        '<div>',
            '<div class="customerID">customerID</div>',
            '<div class="content">other content</div>',
        '</div>'
    ].join(''),
        has_customerid = false;

    var node = dom_construct.toDom(html_snippet);

    if (!has_customerid) {
        query('.customerID', node).orphan();
    }

    document.body.appendChild(node);
});
```

This parses your snippet, checks if `customerID` is present, and removes the specified nodes if it's not.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/XRjKw/) so you can play around with `has_customerid` and doing whatever else you need to the node. You probably want to validate the results of `query(...)`; I left out any error-checking.

Comment: Note that if your snippet isn't in a container, you can use something like  `var node = dom_construct.create('div', {innerHTML: html_snippet});` to create the node that you query and append to the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

If you have JQuery you can do it this way:

```
var html = $(htmlSnippet);
if(!modelHasCustomerID){
    $(".customerID", html).remove();   
}
container.append(html);
```

I am not very familiar with dojo but belive this can be done similar way with dojo.create, dojo.destroy and dojo.query.